# Possible semi-major and semi-minor axes of an elliptical cylinder based on known surface area and height

Tags: geometry

Given a constant surface area $A$ and a known height $h$, how can I manipulate the following equation to isolate for $x$ (or $y$)?

$$A=2\pi xy + h\pi(x+y)(1+\frac{3\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x+y)^2}}{10+\sqrt{4-3\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x+y)^2}}})$$

with

$$ x, y >0$$
(Formula based on Ramanujan's second ellipse circumference approximation.)

Comment: The equation _is_ in terms of $x$ and $y.$ Do you mean you want an equation that gives $x$ in terms of the other quantities? Even if you can get a reasonable equation, how would that help you find an "average" of anything?

Comment: With the area formula you have given there is set of possible $(x,y)$ values. of semi major/minor axes. What is meant by "average"? Did you mean maximum?

Comment: I have edited to include one more condition. Please feel free to change it back if you are in the meanwhile clearer than this. At present  the post has a risk of closure.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I should have clarified that I would like one of the parameters in isolation. Finding the 'average' itself is outside of the scope of the question and was added for context, but specifically I would be able to find a function for the volume at all valid (positive, nonzero) values of x and then integrate.

Comment: You know the question where someone drives up a hill at 30 kph and back down the same path at 60 kph, and we want to know their average speed? And the answer usually regarded as correct is _not_ 45 kph? But 45 kph is exactly what you get if you use $x$ to measure distance along the path and average speed over $x.$ What you're trying to do also sounds like a bad idea (although I couldn't say for sure that it is a bad idea without knowing more context, and I'm not telling you not to do it--it's your choice).

Comment: Another thought: since you are willing to accept an approximate formula already (albeit a rather good one), why not use numerical methods to find the volume for each $x$ and numerical integration to get the average?

Comment: @DavidK While I appreciate your concern, I am entirely capable of finding an average value function (which is beyond the scope of the question in any case). The reason i'm hesitant to use discrete values for approximating the function is that while the value $A$ is a known constant for a given instance of the problem, I would be applying the formula thousands of times with different given areas.

Comment: The volume should scale linearly with $h$ and quadratically with $A/h.$ One average value should be all you need. At least that's what I'd expect for anything that I would call an "average": if you change the units from centimeters to inches you should get a result consistent with scaling every linear dimension of the problem by the same factor.